# Loadrunner - Select which action to execute next

Tags: loadrunner

I'm currently scripting under VuGen and I would like to know if there is any way to choose which action to perform next.

For example I have 3 action in my script,

- in the first action I'm testing the value of a variable and if this value is 0 I want to execute action 2 then action 3
- but if the value is 1 then I only want to execute the action 3.

Is there a way to make this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unschedule the actions in the run time settings
2. These are standard C functions, so....

   if ( myvariable == 0 )
   {
    action2();
   }

   If ( myvariable == 0 || myvariable == 1 )
   {
    action3();
   }

You may want to investigate a 'C' language refresher course.

Comment: I wanted to know if it's possible to do that while doing a replay of the script. Without removing those actions from the run.

Comment: Yes, by following the statements above.   As you are going to decide when the execute them based upon a condition, you remove them from the standard scheduler for actions.  Then you implement some code similar to the above to call the actions yourself as needed.   I am assuming you are new to the tool, have you been assigned a mentor for your first year as a performance tester?   If not then it is an obligation of your employer to provide one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. It's indeed my first year as a performance tester, it's even my first week so I'm not really used to Loadrunner yet.

Comment: Steps to success: (1) Confirm your core skills, address gaps if necessary (you show some gaps here in C programming and tool knowledge).   Go through Process Training.   Go through Product Training.   Be assigned to an internship for up to a year until you are self sufficient.   Becoming a performance tester is no different than becoming a stonemason, electrician, plumber or accountant: Foundation skills, training in process and tools and then finally an internship

Comment: If you have been assigned to a project without a confirmation of your core skills, training in process and tools and assignment of a mentor, then your management team eventually will sacrifice you to save a customer relationship.   This is a well known pattern where the management is more interested in the ability to bill rather than the ability to be successful.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(atoi(lr_eval_string("<{lock_count}>")) > 0)
{       

return 0;

}
else if(atoi(lr_eval_string("<{reflock_count}>")) > 0){
    return 0;
}
```

I used this code to solve my problem. In front of each action that I want to execute only if the var are > 0.
So, if my lock_count or my reflock_count are > 0 then I'll ignore the action and go straight to the next one

Thanks for your time, your answer got me this idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to think about, each time you create a new "Action" within LoadRunner an entirely new .C file is created in the script folder where you save the script. If your code is small enough this may not be a big deal to you, but for me adding bloat to the performance testing script is somewhat self defeating.

What I have come to do is create my own custom functions instead of new actions. I place my custom code at the bottom of the vuser_init section and call them from Action as needed. When you run the script in the Controller all the custom code you create is loaded into memory during the initialization phase as it loads the file vuser_init.c.

Once you have all your functions set up some simple SWITCH statements can run the code you want, all without having to add more files to the script directory.